# How to refresh a page in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I found out that my page **actually** reload/refresh, but require additional reload to see the content I just added. However I've to reload **again** to see the data, **OR** add another data to see the previous data..

I added my controller code below:

**(CreateComment** and **Comment**(display comments) are inside **Details**(details about book) View **)**

**CreateComment**:

```
    public ActionResult CreateComment(Guid id) {
        return View(new CommentToBook { BookId = id });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateComment(CommentToBookVm model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var m = new CommentToBook { Comment = model.Comment, BookId = model.BookId };
            m.UserId = new Guid(Session["UserID"].ToString());
            m.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            db.CommentToBooks.Add(m);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View for createComment**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.BookId)

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Details (have Comment and CreateComment inside)**

```
public ActionResult Details(Guid? id) {

        Book book = db.Books.Find(id);

        return View(book);
    }
```

View

```
<h2>Details</h2>

@Html.Action("Rating", new { id = Model.Id })
<div>


    <h4>Books</h4>
    <hr/>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        </dd>
 @*and so on...*@

   </dl>
</div>

@Html.Action("Comment", new { id = Model.Id })
@Html.Action("CreateComment", new { id = Model.Id })
```

**And the Comment to list all comments.**

```
public ActionResult Comment(Guid? id) {

                var comment = db.CommentToBooks.Where(c => c.BookId == id);

                return View(comment.ToList());
            }
```

view:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            User
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.User.UserName, "VisitUser", new { id = item.UserId }) 
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I think it's about what I am returning in controller, I tried some different alternative but I just end up hitting the error:

```
Description:
```

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 9:  @Html.Action("Comment", new { id = Model.Id })

OR

> child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.

If I try to `RedirectToAction` for `CreateComment` etc.

I would appreciate an example of code as I find it hard to understand new concepts by just words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is returning the view for `CreateComment` method. Looks like you marked this action method as `ChildActions` only. You should not be using ChildAction for a use case like this. ChildActions should be used for rendering something to the view. Ex : A Menu bar in your app.

Even if you remove the `[ChildAction]` from the CreateComment action method, when you return the model back to the form, it is going to render the markup generated by the CreateComment view. That means you will loose the list of comments (which was loaded when you called the Details view).

Ideally, for all data insertion usecases, you should follow **P-R-G** pattern.

PRG stands for **POST** - **REDIRECT**- **GET**. That means, you submit a form and after successfully saving data to db, you do return a redirect result to the client and client(browser) will issue a totally new http request for the GET action method in which you wiil query the db table and return the results.

But since your form is loaded to the main view through a call to the `Html.Action` method, you won't get the desired results (list of comments and the validation messages in same view). One thing to make it to work is, by enabling unobtrusive client side validation. In that case, the form won't be actually submitted to the server. Instead client side validation will be invoked and validation messages will be shown to the user in the same page(no page reload!).

You can enable it by adding reference to these 2 scripts in your view(or layout)

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Redirect to the GET action to show all comments after successful save of the posted comment.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateComment(CommentToBookVm model) 
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid) 
  {
    //your existing code to save data to the table

     return RedirectToAction("Details","Book", new { id=model.BookId} );

  }

  // Hoping that the below code might not execute as client side validation
 //  must have prevented the form submission if there was a validation error.
  return View(model);
}
```

**Another option which does not rely on just client side validation** is to create a flat view model which has the list of existing comments and properties for the new comment form. When you submit the form, if validation fails, reload the Comments property again and return the view model back to the form.

```
public class ListAndCreateVm
{
  [Required]
  public string NewComment { set;get;}

  public Guid BookId { set;get;}

  public List<CommentVm> Comments { set;get;}
}
public class CommentVm
{
  public string Comment { set;get;}
  public string Author { set;get;}
}
```

and in your Details action, load Comments and send this to the view

```
public ActionResult Details(Guid id)
{
   var vm = new ListAndCreateVm { BookId= id};
   vm.Comments = GetComments(id);
   return View(vm);
}
private List<CommentVm> GetComments(Guid bookId)
{
   return db.CommentToBooks.Where(c => c.BookId == bookId)
                                  .Select(x=> new CommentVm { Comment = x.Comment})
                                  .ToList();
}
```

and in your view

```
@model ListAndCreateVm
@foreach(var c in Model.Comments)
{
  <p>@c.Comment</p>
}
<h4>Create new comment</h4>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.NewComment)
  @Html.HiddenFor(f=>f.BookId)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now along with using PRG pattern, make sure to reload Comments property of the view model when Model validation fails

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(ListAndCreateVm model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // to do : Save
    return RedirectToAction("Details,"Book",new { id=model.BookId});
  } 
  //lets reload comments because Http is stateless :)
  model.Comments = GetComments(model.BookId);
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shyju; I was using this pattern, but I didn't know it has a name!

Comment: hmm, it wont resolve the parameter. `Comment` and `Details` method are within the same Controller. "Represents text as series of Unicode characters"

Comment: it wont resolve which parameter ? I changed "Comment" to "Details" as the action method name for `RedirectToAction`. Are you trying that version ?

Comment: @Hackerman True for many patterns. We use it in our code base but we don't realize that we are using it! PRG is must for any form submissions as it prevents duplicate submissions effectively.

Comment: `Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.` at Line `101:@Html.Action("CreateComment", new { id = Model.Id })` inside `Details` view(at bottom). **EDIT**: I think the solution is somehow displaying `CreateComment` in other way in in `Details` in order to be able to use `RedirectToAction` in `CreateComment`?

Comment: @Nyprez You should not be using ChildAction for a use case like this. Use client side validation. See the updated answer.

Comment: @Nyprez I posted an alternate approach which does not simply rely on client side validation but make uses server side validation as well.

Comment: @Shyju at the end of `return db.CommentToBooks.Where(c => c.BookId == id).Select(x=> new { CommentVm { Comment = x.Comment}).ToList();` I think you missed a ";" or something, cant make it work.

Comment: Yes. Fixed that too! I did not try the code in a C# file. Wrote it here. So all these small issues. Hopefully this is the last one. Thanks for pointing out @skylake

Comment: @Shyju Not sure where to put the View-code. If I put it in details-view then everything from details will be faulty.

Comment: @Shyju I forgot to mention that I didn't use `ChildAction` as I had no clue about it till you mentioned it. I think the ChildAction-behavior is resulted by :`@Html.Action("CreateComment", new { id = Model.Id })` inside `Details`. 1. It's called inside `Details`. 2. Once a comment is created it returns to run `Details` again. 3. `Details` tried to  re-run `CreateComment` again as it's inside `Details`. Could that explain the behavior of ChildAction?

Comment: What you mean faulty ? Can you be specific ?

Comment: If I put your view-code inside `Details` then it take over "model". For e.g.  `model.Title` won't work anymore because `@model ListAndCreateVm` seems to take over `Model`. I can only list stuff from `ListAndCreate` in model, not `Book` anymore. Seems like it doesn't matter where I put it.

Comment: You need to add properties to the `ListAndCreateVm` view model as needed. I added only BookId. You can add whatever property you need and populate the value of that in the GET Action method. So tthe short answer is, go ahead and add the Title (or any other properties you want) to the view model. If it is going to show the book details (I would rename the view model from `ListAndCreateVm` to `BookDetailsVm` because that makes more sense.